# Seeking Moderate to High Resolution Forest Fire Before and After Images

Tags: data, modis, landsat, forest-ecology, sentinel

I'm trying to search through the moderate to high-resolution satellite image data sets for imaging that shows forests both before and after a forest fire in order to assess the burn severity and the spatial boundaries of the fire. I'm confident that the data I'm looking for exists in some of the Earth Engine data sets in the data catalog (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets), but each data set is so large that I don't know how to go about finding the slices of them that would work for this project.

Is there anyone reading this familiar with some portion of one of these datasets that satisfies this description or who could offer guidance on how to efficiently search the datasets for what I'm looking for?

I have never worked with GIS data before.

Comment: You can take a look at MTBS. The should have the processed imagery, deltaNBR and classified burn severity. https://www.mtbs.gov/

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.